# How to break feed line according to page width?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml-parsing

I don't know exactly how to say that, I'll try to express myself here.
I have this feed url :

> http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_boutique_show_ads.php?boutiqueid=37930-895835&currencypos=0&display_img=1&diplay_name=1&diplay_price=1&thumbsize=80%&truncate_desc=15&numrows=1&numcols=20&colorname=000000&colorprice=E30000&bkcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=FFFFFF&self_target=0&

It pulls out 15 items at once, it's like a store. The problem is that it won't break the line once it reaches the full width, on the other hand, it will just add a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom.

What I need to do is, instead of displaying the items like this:

```
|--- WIDTH 300px ---|

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I need to display them like this:

```
|--- WIDTH 300px ---|

01 02 03 04 05 06

07 08 09 10 11 12

13 14 15
```

Here is my code :

http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_boutique_show_ads.php?boutiqueid=37930-895843&currencypos=0&display_img=1&diplay_name=1&diplay_price=1&thumbsize=80%&truncate_desc=15&numrows=1&numcols=20&colorname=000000&colorprice=E30000&bkcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=FFFFFF&self_target=0&");
       echo ($a);
     ?>

I also would like to know if it's possible to use javascript instead of php.

Comment: http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_boutique_show_ads.php?boutiqueid=37930-895843&currencypos=0&display_img=1&diplay_name=1&diplay_price=1&thumbsize=80%&truncate_desc=15&numrows=3&numcols=5&colorname=000000&colorprice=E30000&bkcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=FFFFFF&self_target=0&

Comment: However, that api returns a complete html page with `<html><head>..` etc, so is meant for displaying in an iframe, not directly outputting into html - see if they have  json/xml api instead

Comment: I updated the feed with the JSON url that was available in their site. Check it out.

Comment: It sill pulls a full page, but it uses div now, instead of Tables.

Comment: I cant see any difference tbh - its certainly not json

Comment: I have an option to export JSON, but if I do that, I'll not have a dynamic page, just a static one. Can't see anywhere to find a json link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have access another api endpoint (eg one that produces json or xml), then you will have to parse the html to strip the unwanted cruft;

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTMLFile('http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_boutique_show_ads.php?boutiqueid=37930-895835&currencypos=0&display_img=1&diplay_name=1&diplay_price=1&thumbsize=80%&truncate_desc=15&numrows=1&numcols=20&colorname=000000&colorprice=E30000&bkcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=FFFFFF&self_target=0&');

$products = array();

    //Loop through each <td> tag in the dom and extract inner html

foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('td') as $p) {
    $children  = $p->childNodes;
    $phtml = '';
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        $phtml.= $p->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }
    echo '<div class="product">' . $phtml . '</div>';
}
```

Css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .product{
        width: 100px; float:left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Steve, look at this http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895812&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=994